# Query doenot work for md5(id) in where

Tags: mysql, sql

Folowing is my query which runs fine when I use `ID` in my where clause but it doesnot when I wrap the ID in `md5(id)` and gave following error. 
`#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='`

Is there a way I can make the query work by wraping the id in `md5(id)` :

```
SELECT md5(id),username FROM login
where md5(id) NOT IN (select user_id from logged where given_by = 'drothy') 
ORDER BY dt_created DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error already said that you have two different collations in your tables, change one collation of one table to same as other table

```
    ALTER TABLE login CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

if your table is already `latin1_swedish_ci` then change logged table to `latin1_swedish_ci`
or use both `utf8_general_ci`

and then run your query normal

- do it better one time Like that , and not every time you do collate in your queries.

EDIT:

If you are using mysqli, issue this command right after connecting:

```
  $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

This will set your connection encoding to UTF8 (same as your table uses).

Comment: on doing the alter table I got this error `#1115 - Unknown character set: 'latin1_swedish_ci'`